# Tmux force resize?

Tags: linux, command-line, tmux, headless

I'm using tmux as a tty for a project I'm running, using capture-pane to get the info off and send-keys to interact with. I need the terminal size to be 40x24 so data doesnt run off the screen, and I can't find any methods of accomplishing this. I'd like to do this from the command line rather than keybinds as well since it will be the final step in an initializing script that creates all the handling processes for interacting with the hardware I'm using it with and simply get a live properly sized window at the end to read and write to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `-x` and `-y` when you create the session to set the size:

```
tmux new -x40 -y24 -d
```

However, it will be resized when you attach unless you ask tmux not to do so. In newer tmux versions, you can do this by setting the `window-size` option, either globally or per window:

```
tmux new -x40 -y24 -d
tmux set -g window-size manual
```

Or:

```
S=$(tmux new -x40 -y24 -dP)
tmux set -t$S window-size manual
```

Or you could use `resize-window` to do it temporarily, which will automatically set the `window-size` option:

```
W=mysession:mywindow
tmux resizew -t$W -x40 -y24
whatever
tmux set -ut$W window-size
```

If your tmux is too old for `window-size`, look at the `force-width` and `force-height` options.